# Python program does not behave as intended

Tags: python, logic

I'm writing my first short programs with Python. This program should stop after the third wrong guess. The program works as expected with the first question, and stops itself after three wrong guesses.

However, I cannot understand why, with the second question, after the third wrong guess, the first question is repeated.

```
easy_text = '''Hello __1__!'  In __2__ this is particularly easy; all you 
have to do is type in: __3__ "Hello __1__!" Of course, that isn't a very 
useful thing to do. However, it is an example of how to output to the user 
using the __3__ command, and produces a program which does something, so it 
is useful in that capacity..'''

def split_string():
    global easy_text_splitted
    easy_text_splitted = easy_text.split(" ")
    return None

def level1():
    print """You will get 3 guesses per problem

    The current paragraph reads as such:"""
    print easy_text
    return first_question(3)

def first_question(guesses):
    while guesses > 0:
        split_string()
        first_answer = raw_input("What should be substituted in for __1__?")
        if first_answer.lower() == "world":
            easy_text_splitted[1] = first_answer
            easy_text_splitted[19] = first_answer
            new_easy_text = " ".join(easy_text_splitted)
            print new_easy_text
            second_question(3)
        else:
            guesses -= 1
            print "That's not the answer I expected. You have " + 
            str(guesses) + " guess(es) left"
            return first_question(guesses)

def second_question(guesses):
    while guesses > 0:
        split_string()
        second_answer = raw_input("What should be substituted in for 2?")
        if second_answer.lower() == "python":
            easy_text_splitted[4] = second_answer
            new_easy_text = " ".join(easy_text_splitted)
            print new_easy_text
        else:
            guesses -= 1
            print "That's not the answer I expected. You have \n " + 
            str(guesses) + " guess(es) left"
            return second_question(guesses)

def level_selection(index):
    level = raw_input("Choose the desired level of difficulty: easy, \n 
    medium, or hard ")
    if level.lower() == "easy":
        return level1()
    if level.lower() == "medium":
        return level2
    if level.lower() == "hard":
        return level3 
    else:
        print "Error"
        index -= 1
        if index > 0:
            return level_selection(index)
    return "Bye!"

print level_selection(3)


level2 = "You selected medium"
level3 = "You selected hard"
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the value of `guesses` was in `first_question` when `second_question` was called, it is the same when it returns, so the loop continues, and repeats the first question.

Using a debugger will help you follow how this works.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using pythontutor.com, but still I'm able to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Maybe if you explained where your understanding comes up short, someone could help.

Comment: My question is: how can I make the program to stop after a third wrong guess is entered, instead of repeating the first question.

Comment: You've already asked that; what you haven't done is show any effort toward trying to solve the problem, or even understanding why there is a problem.

Comment: I'm doing an effort trying to make sense of it, but i'm stuck and that's why I came here asking for help. Thanks for being so encouraging and helpful, mr. Expert.

Comment: I was trying to determine what specifically you need help with, but I guess I'll be on my way.  Good luck.